# Question title font renders 0 (number zero) much like o (lower-case letter)

Tags: feature-request, design, fonts

Currently, the font specification calls `Georgia` as the primary serif font for question titles. While undeniably an attractive font, its zero renders almost exactly the same as a lower case letter 'o'. This introduces a significant level of ambiguity:

[image: Georgia rendering a zero]

While I think it extremely unlikely that there is a serif font that is readily available on most Unix user's machines that would have a slashed or dotted zero (the ideal), with only a small tweak to the CSS, it would be possible to improve the rendering of zeros *for most users*:

[image: Times as the default]

I'm reluctant to suggest a significant change as I think the overall look of the site is extremely professional - however, for a site for coders and geeks,  having ambiguous zeros is rather unfortunate[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/825Vg.png).

With only a small change to the stylesheet, this can be improved. From:

```
#question-header .question-hyperlink {
     color: #155078;
     font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
     font-size: 24px;
     ...
}
```

to:

```
#question-header .question-hyperlink {
     color: #155078;
     font-family: "Times New Roman",Times,serif;
     font-size: 28px;
     ...
}
```

Is this something that others are similarly exercised about? Could it be considered for a change?

Other example questions where this has an impact (mentioned in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1519466#1519466)):

- [What is signal 0 in a trap command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17314/what-is-signal-0-in-a-trap-command)
- [what is commit=0 for ext4? does mdadm not support it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1446/what-is-commit-0-for-ext4-does-mdadm-not-support-it)
- [Message while booting : “can't allocate mem resource [0xc0000000-0xbfffffff]”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10287/message-while-booting-pci-00000000-0-bar-0-cant-allocate-mem-resource-0x)
- [ext4 overrides my commit=100 mount option with commit=0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16804/ext4-overrides-my-commit-100-mount-option-with-commit-0)

#### UPDATE

Updated to highlight a couple of particularly egregious examples:

[image: A shocker...]

[image: another more recent example of fail]

Comment: Your CSS might not be the final correct change. `#question-header` might not catch the ones in the question list, a more generic `a.question-hyperlink` might be in order. In any case that's for the site designer to work out.

Comment: Looks like “this” bug has returned from the dead, thanks to the One-Font-To-Rule-Them-All responsivity theme.  But seriously, these are simply text figures. That’s how they are *supposed* to work. There is no bug. But probably you would do better with a face that had slashed zeroes. Courier? :)

Comment: See please [this search for 0s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=0).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I too think this design could use addressing. As I [mentioned in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1519348#1519348) I have been bothered by this before and was going to bring it up on Meta and kept forgetting. Thanks for bringing it up.

I'm not attached to any particular choice so long as it's glyphs for key characters that matter to Unix related questions (like the number zero and letter o) are sufficiently distinct.

Comment: And yet still nothing changed after almost 10 years... NICE

Answer (score 3):

Historical note: this was changed to use Liberation Serif between April 16th of 2013 and August 9th 2018; this effectively resolved the issue. Since the more recent switch back to Georgia for the title font, the issue has returned (at least on Windows).

Comment: Thank you: that looks *so* much better.

Comment: [Sklivvz](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/users/6869/sklivvz) is the man. I believe he even uses some Apple-flavored Unix...

Comment: This still looks poor to me. Is it because I don't have the Liberation font?

Comment: I don't know, @Barmar - *do* you have the Liberation font?

Comment: Probably not. Unless it's a standard font on OS X Snow Leopard, I probably don't.

Comment: I don't think I've ever installed any third-party fonts. And I don't see any results in the browser if I remove Liberation from the fonts of that style, so it must be using Georgia.

Comment: I recommend that you remove that shiny red `status-completed` from this post, since it no longer completed nor fixed, but indeed **regressed** thanks to Mordor’s shiny new One-Font-To-Rule-Them-All ⁽ᵃⁿᵈ ⁱⁿ ᵗʰᵉ ᵈᵃʳᵏⁿᵉˢˢ ᵇⁱⁿᵈ ᵗʰᵉᵐ⁾ policy.

Comment: Grrr... Weird thing here is that it looks *great* on Android - 0 O o are all very distinct in size and shape. On Windows, 0 and o are very, very close in size and style. @tchrist

Answer (score 2):

When writing by hand I always slash my zeroes and sevens.

Don't know which font does that (zeroes, 7 is already non-ambiguous) but I'd like to see it used.