# Zero ("0") is looking like a lower case letter "o" in titles: o0O0o

Tags: feature-request, design, fonts

The number 0 is looking like the letter o.

Someone already drew attention to this almost 10 years ago, but nothing has changed.

I recommend to change the font.

[Question title font renders 0 (number zero) much like o (lower-case letter)](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/716/question-title-font-renders-0-number-zero-much-like-o-lower-case-letter)

Comment: From the Q/A you linked to: something [changed and then was changed back](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1219/315749). Surprisingly, the evident issue with "0" (and numbers in Georgia font in general) seems to have been rarely pointed out network-wide (e.g. [this Q/A](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4973) on gis.SE).

Comment: Background information I found on main Meta: fonts [have been standardized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311033/410681) during the rollout of the [responsive design theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314979/410681), and site themes can apparently only choose between "serif" and "sans-serif" fonts, as defined by the [Stack Overflow font stack](https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/typography/#fonts). U&L seems to have [preferred a serif font for titles](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1220/315749), though I wasn't able to find any broader discussion.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you mean. I just saw [Why is \`-r\` seemingly ignored when used with \`-0\` in GNU xargs?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/600560) and tried to fix it presuming the OP had a typo and had put `-o` instead of `-0` there.

Comment: It's [not the first time](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4955/108618) our *technical* sites are crippled by an aesthetic(?) decision.

Comment: I wouldn't call others an aesthetic decision.  Font is definitely an issue with `oO0` characters with the same origin looking like one another is a common pattern caused by unicode.  My favorite example to date is `μ` [U+039C](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03bc/index.htm) and `µ` [U+00B5](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00B5/index.htm).  The micro sign is the greek letter mu, but they have different Unicode code points.  That gave us a right headache when porting a scientific database.